# Loading byte data to a picture box

Tags: vb.net

I have saved an image in database using following code.

```
ofd.ShowDialog()
    vrPicHolder = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName)
    Dim drPic As DataRow
    drPic = DsPic.tblPicTest.NewRow
    drPic.Item("Picture") = vrPicHolder
    DsPic.tblPicTest.Rows.Add(drPic)
    taPic.Update(DsPic.tblPicTest)
```

Now I want to display this image in a picture box.  I tried

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(vrPicHolder)
```

But it says can not convert Byte() to string.  Please advise how to load this picture.
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method you're calling expects a string that's the filename of an image.  You need to pass it the filename of an image that is a BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG or TIFF format.

[Image.FromFile Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx)

What you should be doing is this:

```
Dim pictureBytes as New MemoryStream(vrPicHolder)
PicutureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(pictureBytes)
```

[Image.FromStream Method (Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much.
please also advise how to call it in SSRS.  From file I could use expression
=file://image.jpg
what about stream?

Comment: Sorry - can't help you on the SSRS; I haven't worked with that.  You might post it as a separate question.

Comment: I tried your code but it gives error on pictureBytes (overload resolution)  I also added Imports.system.io

Answer (score 1):

This is because Image.FromFile Method expects FilePath as String. Its like importing a file from some given path.See [Image.FromFile Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx)

[Image.FromStream Method (Stream)](http://Image.FromStream%20Method%20%28Stream%29) is the remedy for this.

One more thing ,you should not set the complete Image to the database . Instead save the image into some physical path and refer this path from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://windevblog.blogspot.com/2008/08/convert-image-to-byte-array-and-vice.html