# DirectCast MySQL BLOB to a PictureBox

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

```
frmSingleRecord.picImage.Image = DirectCast(sdr("photo_index"), Image)
```

This code is from my `MysqlDataReader` and the `photo_index` is the `Blob` from my **database**. I got error from this code.

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type
>   'System.Drawing.Image'.

If its possible to `DirectCast` a `Blob` to PictureBox how can I do this right? If not any suggestion will be great!

Comment: No, it's not, and nor is it possible with `CType`.

Comment: How can i do it with `CType`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading byte data to a picture box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869777/loading-byte-data-to-a-picture-box)

Comment: Firstly, you're not even trying to convert anything to a `PictureBox`.  You're trying to convert a `Byte` array to an `Image` that can then be displayed in a `PictureBox`.  As for casting, you can't cast something as something it's not.  The idea of casting is that you change the type of the reference via which you access an object, not the type of the object you're referencing.  If something is not an `Image` then it can't be cast as an `Image`.  Have you ever heard the expression "to cast something in a different light"? That's the same "cast" that we use in programming.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Noted (y)

Comment: If the answer helped. please click the up arrow.  Up voting any question or answer which you find helpful helps other users find good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, you cant cast a byte array to a `PictureBox` which is a UI control, but you can cast the binary BLOB to `Byte()` so you can create an image from it.  Assuming you did save an `Image` as `Byte()` to the DB:

```vb
...
If rdr.Read() Then
    buff = TryCast(rdr.Item(1), Byte())
    If buff IsNot Nothing Then
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(buff)
            pBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        End Using
    End If
End If
```

First, `TryCast` tries to cast the field data to `Byte()` to avoid an Exception which could happen if only some rows have image data for them.  If the cast worked, an image is created from the `Byte()` using a `MemoryStream` and assigned to the `PictureBox.Image` property.  This is probably the reverse of how you got the data into the DB.

Note that you have created a new `Image`, so it is up to you to also dispose of it when you are done with it.