# Unable to delete image file loaded in PictureBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

My vb.net application downloads pictures from the internet and displays it as a PictureBox.

When exiting the program, I want it to delete the shown files that have been downloaded, however Im not able to do so. The Debugger throws an error saying the specified file cannot be accessed as its still used in the picture box.
I already tried using the Dispose() Method which didn't work.

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. This site is for questions regarding specific issues with existing code. As it stands, your question is off-topic because you don't explain what behaviour you're  getting and what errors you get and on what line they occur. Don't let negative votes or votes to close put you off though. Thanks

Comment: @preciousbetine https://pastebin.com/NXWvCeWd

Comment: Edit your post and include the code.

Comment: Also how did you draw the images on the picture boxes. Include the code for that.

Comment: @looxmyy, did you try loading the image from stream as mentioned in answer? This is a common scenario and can be catered with streams.

Comment: @AzazulHaq yes, just did that and this works fine. Its a bit slow though as it downloads a new picture into memory everytime i click on the button that loads the picture

Comment: @looxmyy, loading picture in memory usually don't take longer. Though it depends on the size of the picture and other environmental factors.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you should try loading the image from stream instead of file. This would release the file object from your file system and load image into your application's memory. After that you should be able to remove the file from your file system.

Have a look at [Image.FromStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_FromStream_System_IO_Stream_) method.
And also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869777/loading-byte-data-to-a-picture-box) post.